# ValueError: time data '\r' does not match format '%Y%m%d:%H%M' (match)

Tags: python, dataframe, string-to-datetime

I am trying to read data from an online database and convert the first row to a timestamp.
Although using the right format string in *to_datetime*, but I got the error

`time data '\r' does not match format '%Y%m%d:%H%M' (match)`

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import datetime


lat= 39  #Latitude
lon=-4 #Longitude
mountingplace = "building" 
angle=15 
aspect = 0 

url = "https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/seriescalc?lat={}&lon={}&outputformat=csv&browser=1&startyear=2015&endyear=2016&peakpower=1&mountingplace={}&angle={}&pvcalculation=1&aspect={}&loss=5".format(lat,lon,mountingplace,angle, aspect)

pv=pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', skiprows=10)#, date_parser=custom_date_parser)

pv['time']=pd.to_datetime(pv.time, format="%Y%m%d:%H%M")
```

Comment: What happens if you use `lineterminator="\r\n"` in your call to `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: `ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported` @MattDMo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pv=pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', skiprows=10)#, date_parser=custom_date_parser)
```

Here you are assuming file ending is newline (`\n`), I inspect file and it seem to be using carriagereturn-newline (`\r\n`) endings. Just let `read_csv` to act automatically there, i.e. do

```
pv=pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',', skiprows=10)#, date_parser=custom_date_parser)
```

Also `.time` have some data not compliant with `%Y%m%d:%H%M` format namely

```
17546                           H_sun: Sun height (degree)
17547            T2m: 2-m air temperature (degree Celsius)
17548                   WS10m: 10-m total wind speed (m/s)
17549    Int: 1 means solar radiation values are recons...
17550                             PVGIS (c) European Union
```

So you need to inform [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) what do with it unless fatal malfunction is desired behavior, you might do e.g.

```
pv['time_parsed']=pd.to_datetime(pv.time, format="%Y%m%d:%H%M", errors="coerce")
```

then non-compliant values will be turned into `NaT`s.